# How fixed command line in angular 5

Tags: angular, command-line, build

I am working on an application with angular 5 and I am a beginner in angular, I make changes in my application with CLI commands, but I have a problem, how to fix this problem and thank's ( i think the problem in @schematics/angular and not sure) -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- this my files:

```
package.json:


      "dependencies": {
            "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.25",
            "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
            "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0",
            "@angular/cli": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
            "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
            "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
            "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
            "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
            "@angular/material": "^5.0.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
            "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.0",
            "@ngx-pwa/local-storage": "^5.3.1",
            "@schematics/angular": "^7.0.3",
            "@thisissoon/angular-inviewport": "^3.0.1",
            "@thisissoon/angular-scrollspy": "^2.0.0",
"angular-alert-module": "^2.0.3",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^6.2.5",
    "angular-material-expansion-panel": "^0.7.2",
    "angular-notifier": "^4.1.1",
    "angular-simple-scroll-spy": "0.0.2",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.7.1",
    "bootstrap-markdown": "^2.10.0",
    "cd-themify-icons": "0.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.5.1",
    "datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4": "^3.1.3",
    "datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.2.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.8.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-minicolors": "^2.1.10",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
        }
     "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "typescript": "~2.4.2"
      }
```

and angular-cli.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "my-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "web.config.xml"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [

        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/cd-themify-icons/index.css",
        "../node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
        "../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-bs4/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap4.min.css",
        "../node_modules/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css",
        "../node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-markdown/css/bootstrap-markdown.min.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css",
        "./assets/vendors/bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css",
        "../node_modules/morris.js/morris.css",
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
        "../node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css",
        "../node_modules/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.css",
        "./assets/css/main.css",
        "./assets/sass/now-ui-kit.scss",
        "./assets/css/demo.css"


      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
        "../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
        "../node_modules/raphael/raphael.min.js",
        "../node_modules/morris.js/morris.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jvectormap/tests/assets/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js",
        "../node_modules/jvectormap/tests/assets/jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en.js",
        "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-bs4/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js",
        "../node_modules/datatables.net-fixedheader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js",
        "../node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-markdown/js/bootstrap-markdown.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js",
        "./assets/vendors/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js",
        "./assets/vendors/jquery.maskedinput/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js",
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js",
        "./assets/vendors/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js",
        "../node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.min.js",
        "./assets/js/app.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },  
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

and this error :

```
 >ng serve
   Could not determine a single project for the 'serve' target.
Error: Could not determine a single project for the 'serve' target.
    at ServeCommand.getProjectNamesByTarget (D:\Users\z.khlifi\source\repos\runTemplate\runTemplate\node_modules\@angula
r\cli\models\architect-command.js:170:19)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (D:\Users\z.khlifi\source\repos\runTemplate\runTemplate\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\
architect-command.js:33:39)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Comment: Please add your `package.json` and `.angular-cli.json` files as well.

Comment: @SiddAjmera, ok i add the files

Comment: How fixed this ?

Comment: Either change your angular-cli version if want to work on angular 5 else update your project as per your cli version ie. 7 Ref: https://medium.com/@jeroenouw/upgrade-to-angular-7-beta-within-10-minutes-c14fc380edd

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json looks like it's screwed badly.

`"@angular/cli": "^7.0.3"` and `"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",` are not really compatible with each other.

`"@angular/cli": "^7.0.3"` is meant for Angular 7 and not Angular 5.

Following are a few things that you can do:

Replace `"@angular/cli": "^7.0.3"` with `"@angular/cli": "^1.7.4"` and re-run `npm i` and then `ng serve` to see if that works.

Or

Create a new project(in Angular 7 or Angular 5 whatever you prefer). Now this time, without touching the `package.json` file, make the changes that you did initially.